# Passing javascript array in the url

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

How can I pass an array in the url in javascript?

I tried this :

`http://codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/getReport?remarks="+stat+"&sortBy="+sortBy+"&fromDate="+fromDate+"&toDate="+toDate+"&area="+area;`

which the remarks is the one being catch in PHP as an array and `stat` is the javascript array being supplied in the `remarks`. Is there any solution for that?

whenever a time  catch the `remarks` in PHP which I use `$this->input->get_post('remarks')` (since im using codeigniter) i got an error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Thans for your help. :)

Comment: get_post implies you're expecting a POST method? At any rate, you can encode an array for php like so: array[]=x&array[]=y...and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You can encode the array as JSON, with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and decode it in PHP with [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Don't forget to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for the values in the URL, otherwise you might not get the URL you expected.

Comment: I already try an alternative solution, but Thanks aNyway. :) 

my solution, exploding the string into an array. :P Works but isnt reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
http://codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/getReport?get[remarks]="+stat+"&get[sortBy]="+sortBy+"&get[fromDate]="+fromDate+"&get[toDate]="+toDate+"&get[area]="+area;

foreach($_GET['get'] as $get){
 ....
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants and what you propose is unnecessary in any case. If someone wanted to iterate over all query parameters in the URL, they can just do `foreach($_GET as $value){`. There is no need to only use a single query parameter.

Comment: Yeah you are right but, still answers the main questoin :D. There are many way to this question.

Comment: Not really. OP wants to send the value of `remark` as array. I.e. `stat` is an array. He doesn't want to make every parameter an element of an array.